# A function which return a line in a file

Tags: c++

```
string fileCopyLine(fstream fileX, int lineNum){
    string tempStr;
    for(int i = 0; i < lineNum; ++i){
       getline(fileX, tempStr);
    }
    return tempStr;
}
```

I made this function to return the lineNum th line in a file, but error occur. What is wrong with it? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: @J A S O N, what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Please post your error. for more Details

Answer (score 2):

```
string fileCopyLine(fstream fileX, int lineNum){
```

is wrong since `fstream` does not have a copy constructor and you are trying to pass an `fstream` object by value. Use a reference.

```
string fileCopyLine(fstream& fileX, int lineNum){
```